# How to solve this sub query with joins way?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This query I want to will create SQL join way.

```
Select count(*) as testOffers From table1 Where posted_test_id in (Select post_test_id From 
table2 Where user_id = 367) AND is_test_offer=1;
```

Comment: without structure of the tables we cannot tell what columns to join

Answer (score 0):

You try this way  using youn subquery for IN clause a table  for join

```
Select count(*) as testOffers 
From table1 
INNER JOIN  ( 
Select post_test_id From 
table2 Where user_id = 367) t ON t.post_test_id = table1.posted_test_id 
    AND table1.is_test_offer=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to:

```
Select count(*) as testOffers
From table1 t1 join
     (Select distinct post_test_id 
      From table2
      Where user_id = 367
     ) t2
     on t1.posted_test_id = t2.post_test_id
where t1.is_test_offer = 1;
```

Note that the `select distinct` is quite important in the subquery for the two to be semantically equivalent. This is not needed for the `in`, because duplicates do not matter.

It may turn out that `select distinct` is not needed in your particular case.  That would be because the subquery does not return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT count(*) as testOffers From table1  as t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2  ON t1.posted_test_id = t2.posted_test_id
WHERE t2.user_id = 367 AND t1.is_test_offer = 1;
```